# T-test paradox: can adding a single point very far from the null value change the outcome from significant to nonsignificant?

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test, paradox

Let's suppose we have the situation presented in picture $1$. We have a set of $n \in \mathbb{N}$ points that have a mean larger than null hypothesis: $\bar{x}>x_{H_0}$. Also $var(x)$ is such that we can reject null hypothesis with t-test given $\alpha$.

Now we draw one more $x_{i+1}$ from the sample and it takes a very large value of $x$ (picture $2$). We run t-test again. Is it possible that p-value will now be statistically insignificant and we **can not** reject null hypothesis? In other words is there any situation where increase in variance more than offsets change in $\bar{x}$ and thus renders t-test statistically insignificant?

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

Comment: I assume this is a one sample test.  The situation you describe can happen but it may be that the data is not from a normal distribution.

Comment: Yes, this is a one sample test. My intuition is the same as yours but I can not prove it more formally.

Comment: The possibility of this would seem to exist by the [definition of $\alpha$](http://blog.minitab.com/blog/michelle-paret/alphas-p-values-confidence-intervals-oh-my).

Comment: $\alpha$ is unchanged between the two tests.

Comment: You can show that it happens by choosing the data points appropriately to get the result.  With regard to the non-normality you can suspect it but not really prove it.  Goodness of fit tests and outlier tests can be used to reject normality.  But even if you are able to reject normality that does not guarantee that the distribution is non-normal.

Comment: I agree with Vivaldi that this can still happen when $\alpha$ is not changed.

Comment: It is quite a riddle. I haven't been able to tackle it more formally yet. You can run simulations but this is not too elegant.

Comment: I was not implying $\alpha$ would change. Just that if you set $\alpha=0.05$ for example, and the null is true, then you expect to wrongly reject the null 5% of the time, by definition, no?

Comment: That may be true but it doesn't address the question which is only about how a new observation influences the test results.

Comment: @GeoMatt22  We do not draw another sample just one more observation.

Comment: Interesting question... We must also not forget that the larger the sample, the less one single outlier will affect the variance. So this paradox would apply only to very small sample sizes or to extreme outliers with a reasonable sample size...

Comment: I was not trying to imply that, sorry for the mis-communication. My intended point was that everything is probabilistic, so if you put no constraint on *how likely* the "paradox" is (i.e. in repeated experiments of "draw $n$, find significant, then draw 1 more, find insignificant", it is not really a paradox.

Comment: The pseudo-paradox of, ehh... The "contradiction" between the the shift occured (which pulled farther from H0) and the spread enlarged (which pulled towards H0) is apparent only in the view of adding just single data point `i+1`. It _happened so_, with one point. If you add (take from the _population_ implied) `i+2` point it can happen to lie far left, not right. Then, together with `i+1` too, the data will dramatically pull towards H0 _both_ by location and spread. Thus, in the perspective of drawing more and more data from the population the seeming, momentary contradiction/paradox vanishes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Perhaps I'm missing the gist of this question, but: if the next sample is really large variance will blow up, making your t-statistic smaller.

You can test it with made up data, for example

```
#Test if the average value of the sample c(2, 2.5, 3) is significantly different from zero
#> t.test(c(2,2.5,3))$p.value
#[1] 0.01307246
#Now add a 9 to the sample
#> t.test(c(2,2.5,3,9))$p.value
#[1] 0.08627763
```

---

> Is it possible that p-value will now be statistically insignificant
>   and we **can not** reject null hypothesis? In other words is there any
>   situation where increase in variance more than offsets change in
>   $\bar{x}$ and thus renders t-test statistically insignificant?

I think I answered both questions with the code above (but apparently everyone knew it already), so let's delve into the t-statistic now:

$$t={\bar x \over S/\sqrt n}$$

So for the first sample, with size $n_1$:

$$t_1={\bar x_1 \over S_1/\sqrt n_1}$$

Now the second one consists of the first one plus another sample, so:

$$t_2={\bar x_2 \over S_2/\sqrt n_2}$$

With:

$$n_2=n_1+1
\\
\bar x_2 = {n_1\cdot \bar x_1 + x_{n_1+1} \over n_1 + 1}
\\
S_2^2 = {n_1-1\over n_1} \cdot S_1^2 + {(x_{n_1+1}-\bar x_1)^2 \over n_1 + 1}={\left(1\over n_1+1\right)}\left( {n_1^2-1\over n_1} \cdot S_1^2 + (x_{n_1+1}-\bar x_1)^2 \right)$$

$$
t_2=
{n_1\cdot \bar x_1 + x_{n_1+1} \over \sqrt{{n_1^2-1\over n_1} \cdot S_1^2 + (x_{n_1+1}-\bar x_1)^2 }}
$$

EDIT: I actually removed some further steps to avoid implicitly assuming some terms were different from zero.

Defining $\delta = x_{n_1+1} - \bar x_1$

$$
t_2=
{(n_1+1)\cdot \bar x_1 + \delta \over \sqrt{{n_1^2-1\over n_1} \cdot S_1^2 + \delta^2 }}
$$

Assuming $\delta \neq 0$:

$$
t_2=
{\delta \over |\delta|}\cdot {{(n_1+1)\cdot \bar x_1\over \delta} + 1 \over \sqrt{{n_1^2-1\over n_1} \cdot \left(\frac{S_1}{\delta}\right)^2 + 1 }}=\\
=
\text{sign}(\delta)\cdot {{(n_1+1)\cdot \bar x_1\over \delta} + 1 \over \sqrt{{n_1^2-1\over n_1} \cdot \left(\frac{S_1}{\delta}\right)^2 + 1 }}
$$

---

So re-answering

> In other words is there any situation where increase in variance more than offsets change in $\bar{x}$ and thus renders t-test statistically insignificant?

If we make $\delta$ arbitrarily larger than $\bar x_1$ and $S_1$:

$$\lim_{\delta\rightarrow\pm\infty} t_2=\text{sign}(\delta)=\pm 1$$

Indeed:

```
#The original sample is random
x = rnorm(n = 1000, mean = 1E-1, sd = 2)
t.test(x)$st
#       t 
#1.544687 
t.test(c(x,1E10))$st
#t 
#1 
t.test(c(x,-1E10))$st
# t 
#-1
```

So basically you can always make $t=\pm1$ with a single addition to the sample, and the smallest obtainable p-value under this regime, with the degrees of freedom tending to infinity, becomes:

```
2*pnorm(1, lower.tail = FALSE)
#[1] 0.3173105
```

We can also visualize this conclusion looking at the following plot:

```
#Our original sample, here a random normal variable
x = rnorm(n = 1000, mean = 0, sd = 2)

png("ttestparadox.png")
plot(0, 0, xlim = c(-10,10), ylim = c(0,1), type = "n", ylab = "p-value", xlab = "Asinh(new_sample)")
abline(h = 2*pnorm(1, lower.tail = FALSE), lwd = 2L, col = 2)
for(i in seq(-10,10,length.out = 101L)) points(x = i, y = t.test(c(x,sinh(i)))$p., pch = 20L)
dev.off()
```

[image]

I've picked new samples in a $\sinh$ scale so we get to large values faster. Anyways, we can see that, when the new sample $x_{n_1+1}$ deviates from $H_0$, the t-statistic goes to 1.

---

Finally, an example using $\alpha = 0.05$ (shown in blue) where we go from a statistically significant result (shown as the dashed black line, p = 0.02014321) to non-significant results depending on the scale of the new unit sample.

```
set.seed(1234) #reproducible
x = rnorm(n = 1000, mean = 0.2, sd = 2)

png("ttestparadox2.png")
plot(0, 0, xlim = c(-10,10), ylim = c(0,1), type = "n", ylab = "p-value", xlab = "Asinh(new_sample)")
abline(h = 2*pnorm(1, lower.tail = FALSE), lwd = 2L, col = 2)
abline(h = 0.05, lwd = 2L, col = 4)
abline(h = t.test(x)$p.v, lwd = 1, lty = 2)
for(i in seq(-10,10,length.out = 101L)) points(x = i, y = t.test(c(x,sinh(i)))$p., pch = 20L)
dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: @Fireburg Thank you. That is a very concise simulation :) But the gist of the question would be a more formal proof. Maybe I should rephrase the question to make this more apparent.

Comment: @Vivaldi if there is no constraint on the probability of the next sample, you can make it as large as you want (a normal PDF has a tail out to infinity, no?)

Comment: @Vivaldi Tomorrow I'll see if I can sort something out if no one else does it first

Comment: @Vivaldi I think I attacked the problem thoroughly now, give it a look so I can address any other point.

Answer (score 6):

Why is this a paradox?

You are describing a typical situation which we encounter daily: your hypothesis is rejected, then you add one more observation and it's not rejected anymore. I think the reason why it looks like a paradox of sorts is purely psychological. It's called "[framing bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framing_effect_(psychology))" in behavioral economics.

Let's re-frame it. Is it possible that a larger sample does not reject the same hypothesis that a smaller sample does? I'm sure, you'd say "Sure! why not?". Now, take a smaller sample and start adding observations from the larger sample to it. At some point the hypothesis will stop being rejected. At this point it was exactly one observation that changed the outcome. And this is what many of us face quite often, especially when building models on quarterly or monthly economic data. One data point may flip the outcome of the test. That's one reason that I ask my modelers to conduct the robustness check by moving the sample boundaries by a couple of periods and observing whether the results still hold.

UPDATE

Here's the "proof", it's as rigorous as a physicist would bother to produce for himself.

You have a sample: $x_1,x_2$, and $x_2=x_1+\delta$, where $0<\delta<<1$. The mean and the dispersion are:$\bar x_2=x_1+\delta/2$ and $s_2=\delta/2$.

You tested a hypothesis, and rejected it because $\frac{\bar x_2-H_0}{s_2}>c>0$, where $c$ is a critical value corresponding to your significance. The expanded form is
$$\frac{2x_1+\delta-2H_0}{\delta}>c>0$$

Now, you add a third observation to the sample, such that $x_3>\bar x$. The new mean is $$\bar x_3=\frac{2x_1+\delta+x_3}{3}$$
and the dispersion is
$$s_3= \sqrt{\delta^2 + \delta (x1 - x3) + (x1 - x3)^2}\sqrt 2/3$$

Let's test the same hypothesis:
$$\frac{\bar x_3-H_0}{s_3}=\frac{\frac{2x_1+\delta+x_3}{3}-H_0}{\sqrt{\delta^2 + \delta (x1 - x3) + (x1 - x3)^2}\sqrt 2/3}$$
$$=\frac{2x_1+\delta+x_3-3H_0}{\sqrt{\delta^2 + \delta (x1 - x3) + (x1 - x3)^2}\sqrt 2}$$
$$\lim_{\delta\to 0}\frac{\bar x_3-H_0}{s_3}=\frac{2x_1+x_3-3H_0}{\sqrt{ (x1 - x3)^2}\sqrt 2}
=\frac{2x_1+x_3-3H_0}{(x3 - x1)\sqrt 2}$$

Let's do a trick here:
$$=\frac{x_3-x_1+3x_1-3H_0}{(x3 - x1)\sqrt 2}
=\left(1+3\frac{x_1-H_0}{(x3 - x1)}\right)\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$$
If you pull $x_3$ far to the right so that $x_3-x_1>>x_1-H_0$ then you get
$$\lim_{\delta\to 0\\x_3\to\infty}\frac{\bar x_3-H_0}{s_3}
=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\approx 0.71$$

Notice, how you could make your test stats arbitrarily large by picking a small $\delta$ in the original sample:
$$\lim_{\delta\to 0}\frac{\bar x_2-H_0}{s_2}=\infty$$

This simply demonstrates the point that @whuber emphasized in his comment: the test statistic is defined by a combination of inputs including the original sample mean and variance, the additional observation, critical value of the test statistic and the value $H_0$. You have a bunch if inputs with which you can easily construct an example that would reproduce your "paradox".

However, I go back to my point of "framing bias": by wording your question in such a way that all the focus is on the new observation, you made it sound as if there was only little input that flips the situation upside down, while in reality there are all these other inputs that I just mentioned.

Comment: You missed the entire point of the paradox. You add one point which is actually more removed from H0 than any other observation, but in spite of this can still make previously significant test insignificant.

Comment: Nevertheless, Vivaldi, this answer goes to the crux of the matter: the *reason* for why the test becomes insignificant is immaterial. The salient fact is that the test statistic--which balances a mean against a standard deviation--moved out of the critical region.  What you might want to consider, though, is whether the appearance of such an outlier ought to cause you to change your assumption that the sampling distribution of the mean is approximately normal.  If there is any paradox, it might lie in forgetting that the $t$ statistic does not depend on the mean alone.